# Convert to f32 in trait implementation of generic

Tags: rust

To learn rust i tried to implement a generic image class/object.

I have problem with the Image::save(...) function and the implementation from Pixel::gray() of RgbaGeneric.

The compiler say i have to use From or Into trait. But i dont know how the syntax has to look. All atempts to get it works fails.

```rust
mod image {
    use std::fmt;

    use std::path::Path;
    use std::io::Write;
    use std::fs::File;

    #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
    pub struct RgbaGeneric<T> {
        r: T, g: T, b: T, a: T,
    }

    trait Pixel<T> {
        fn red(&self) -> T;
        fn green(&self) -> T;
        fn blue(&self) -> T;
        fn alpha(&self) -> T;
        fn gray(&self) -> T;
    }

    impl<T> Pixel<T> for RgbaGeneric<T> {
        fn red(&self) -> T { return self.r;}
        fn green(&self) -> T { return self.g; }
        fn blue(&self) -> T { return self.b; }
        fn alpha(&self) -> T { return self.a; }
        fn gray(&self) -> T {
           return (self.r as f32 * 0.21 +
                   self.g as f32 * 0.72 +
                   self.b  as f32 * 0.07) as T;
        }
    }

    impl<T> RgbaGeneric<T> {
        pub fn new(r: T, g: T, b: T, a: T) -> RgbaGeneric<T> {
            RgbaGeneric { r, g, b, a }
        }
    }

    pub type RgbaU8 = RgbaGeneric<u8>;

    pub struct Image<T> {
        width: usize, height: usize, data: Vec<T>,
    }

    pub type ImageRgbaU8 = Image<RgbaU8>;

    impl<T> Image<T>
    where
        T: Clone + Pixel<T>
    {
        pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize, val: T) -> Image<T> {
            Image {
                width,
                height,
                data: vec![val; width * height],
            }
        }

        pub fn width(&self) -> usize { return self.width; }
        pub fn height(&self) -> usize { return self.height; }
        pub fn pixel_count(&self) -> usize {
            return self.width * self.height;
        }

        pub fn pixels(&self) -> &[T] { return self.data.as_slice(); }

        pub fn pixel(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> &T {
            return &self.data[self.index(x, y)];
        }

        pub fn set_pixel(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, pixel: T) {
            let idx = self.index(x, y);
            self.data[idx] = pixel;
        }

        pub fn save(&self, filename: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
            let path = Path::new(filename);
            let mut file = try!(File::create(&path));
            let header = format!("P6 {} {} 255\n", self.width, self.height);
            try!(file.write(header.as_bytes()));
            for y in 0..self.height() {
                for x in 0..self.width() {
                    let pix = self.pixel(x,y);
                    try!(file.write(pix.red()));
                    try!(file.write(pix.green()));
                    try!(file.write(pix.blue()));
                }
            }
            return Ok(());
        }

        fn index(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
            return y * &self.width + x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the `gray` method should look like this:

```
impl<T> Pixel<T> for RgbaGeneric<T> where
        f32: std::convert::From<T>,
        T: std::convert::From<f32>{
    fn red(&self) -> T { return self.r;}
    fn green(&self) -> T { return self.g; }
    fn blue(&self) -> T { return self.b; }
    fn alpha(&self) -> T { return self.a; }
    fn gray(&self) -> T {
       return (Into::<f32>::into(self.r) * 0.21 +
               Into::<f32>::into(self.g) * 0.72 +
               Into::<f32>::into(self.b) * 0.07).into();
    }
}
```

In the block's header, we say that our `T` may be converted to and from `f32` type and then we use `into()` method because `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types (compiler implies that `T` may be any type).

Comment: Thanks you, very easy then you know how to write it. The same should be applied to save method of image?